# React - Formulario para enviar datos por POST

Tags: html5, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactstrap

Tengo este código que muestra un formulario con inputs y al darle al botón de submit envia los datos por POST a un endpoint.

El código funciona correctamente, pero para cada input tengo un evento para recoger el valor y guardarlo en this.state, mi pregunta es si se puede hacer esto de otra forma.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button , Form  } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Profile extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        weight : '',
        height: '',
        imc: '',
    };

    this.handleChangeWeight= this.handleChangeWeight.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeHeight= this.handleChangeHeight.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeImc= this.handleChangeImc.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

}


handleChangeWeight(event) {
    this.setState({
        weight: event.target.value,
    })
}

handleChangeHeight(event) {
    this.setState({
        height: event.target.value,
    })
}

handleChangeImc(event) {
    this.setState({
        imc: event.target.value,
    })
}


handleSubmit(event) {
    fetch('http://test-url.local/api/user', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            weight : this.state.weight,
            height : this.state.height,
            imc : this.state.imc,
        })
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}


render() {

    var divStyle = {
        color: 'red',
        margin: '150px 150px 160px 350px',
    };

    return (
        <div style={divStyle}>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicSuplementos">
                    <Form.Check id="suplementos" type="checkbox" label="Suplementos" />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicWeight">
                    <Form.Label>Peso</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="weight" onChange={this.handleChangeWeight} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicHeight">
                    <Form.Label>Altura</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="height" name="height" placeholder="height" onChange={this.handleChangeHeight} />
                </Form.Group>


                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicImc">
                    <Form.Label>Imc</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="imc" name="imc" placeholder="imc" onChange={this.handleChangeImc} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Enviar</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Copiado/pegado desde [las guías de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs):

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

Y luego aplicado a tus inputs:

```
    <Form>
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicSuplementos">
        <Form.Check id="suplementos" type="checkbox" label="Suplementos" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicWeight">
        <Form.Label>Peso</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          id="weight"
          name="weight"
          placeholder="weight"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicHeight">
        <Form.Label>Altura</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          id="height"
          name="height"
          placeholder="height"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicImc">
        <Form.Label>Imc</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          id="imc"
          name="imc"
          placeholder="imc"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Enviar</Button>
    </Form>
```